# Check the correctness of the statements about eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and $\Phi$ an endomorphism of $V$.

I want to check if the following statements are correct or not.

> 1. If $\Phi^2=\Phi$, then $\Phi$ has no other eigenvalues than $0$ and $1$.

This statement is correct.

Let $\lambda\in \mathbb{K}$ an eigenvaulue of $\Phi$, $v\in V\setminus\{0\}$ a corresponding eigenvector.

Then it holds that $\Phi (v)=\lambda \cdot v$ and $\Phi^2(v)=\Phi \left (\Phi (v)\right )=\Phi (\lambda v)=\lambda \cdot \left (\lambda \cdot v\right )=\lambda^2\cdot v$.

Since $\Phi^2=\Phi$, it follows that $\lambda^2\cdot v=\lambda \cdot v\Rightarrow \lambda^2\cdot v-\lambda \cdot v=0\Rightarrow \left (\lambda^2-\lambda \right )\cdot v=0$.

Since $v\neq 0$ it must be $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$. From that we get that 
$\lambda\left (\lambda-1\right )=0$. So it is either $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$.

Is everything correct?

> 2. If $\Phi^2$ has the eigenvalue $\lambda^2$, then $\Phi$ has the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Could you give me a hint for this statement?

> 3. If $\Phi$ is bijective and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\Phi$, then $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $\Phi^{-1}$.

Let $\lambda\in \mathbb{K}$ an eigenvaulue of $\Phi$, $v\in V\setminus\{0\}$ a corresponding eigenvector.

Then it holds that $\Phi (v)=\lambda  v$.

Since $\Phi$ is bijective, it s invertible, i.e. $\Phi^{-1}$ exists.

So we get $\Phi^{-1}\left (\Phi (v)\right )=\Phi^{-1}\left (\lambda  v\right )\Rightarrow v=\Phi^{-1}\left (\lambda  v\right )$.

Since $\Phi$ is a linear map, $\Phi^{-1}$ is also linear, or not?

So we get $v=\lambda  \Phi^{-1}\left (v\right )\Rightarrow \Phi^{-1}\left (v\right )=\lambda^{-1}v$.

But how do we know that $\lambda$ is not equal to $0$ ?

From $\Phi^{-1}\left (v\right )=\lambda^{-1}v$ we get $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $\Phi^{-1}$, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks good to me.
2. Consider $1\times 1$ matrices and find a counterexample
3. $\lambda\neq0$ because $\Phi$ is injective. No injective endomorphism can have $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: 2. By $1\times 1$ do you mean a matrix that consider just one element? 3. Why can an injective endomorphism not have $0$ as an eigenvalue?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, I mean $V=\Bbb K$. Say $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$ to make it a bit easier. And they $0$ as eigenvalue means non-injective is really something you ought to try to prove yourself.

Comment: 2. But isn't a 1x1 matrix equal to an element? Is the eigenvalue then that element?

Comment: @MaryStar That is true. A $1\times 1$ matrix is automatically diagonal, and that one value is its eigenvalue. Now, if $\Phi^2 = [\lambda^2]$, must $\Phi$ be $[\lambda]$?

Comment: But if we have just one element isn't the implication $\Phi^2 = [\lambda^2] \Rightarrow \Phi=[\lambda]$ true?

Comment: Not at all. There are _two_ distinct linear maps $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ whose square is $[\lambda^2]$, and $[\lambda]$ is just one of them.

Comment: Do you mean for $\lambda=-1$ ?

Comment: If $\lambda = -1$, and $\Phi = [1]$, then that's a counterexample, yes.

Comment: I got stuck right now.. Then we have $\Phi^2=[1]$. The eigenvalue is $\lambda=-1$, or not? But how do we get a contradiction?

Comment: Because $\lambda^2 = 1$ is an eigenvalue of $\Phi^2 = [1]$, but $\lambda = -1$ is not an eigenvalue of $\Phi = [1]$.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks a lot!! :-)